# Springboot attach @PersistenceContext EntityManager to a @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am getting following Error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 4: D1EntityManager,D2EntityManager,BaseEntityManager,oldDbEntityManager

I have declared in different files those 4 `EntityManagers` following this template:

**RepositoryConfigurationTemplate**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "...myReposPackages...",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = ConfigurationChanges.ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME,
    transactionManagerRef = ConfigurationChanges.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME
)
@ComponentScan("...myScanPackages...")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class MyRepoConfigClass {
  ...
  ...
  public final static String ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME = "...EntityManagerSingleConstant..."; // D1EntityManager / D2EntityManager / BaseEntityManager / oldDbEntityManager for different classes
  public final static String TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME = "...TransactionManagerSingleConstant..."; // D1TransactionManager / D2TransactionManager / BaseTransactionManager / oldDbTransactionManager for different classes

  @Bean(name=ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
  @Qualifier(ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) // Not sure if this is needed, I just added it trying to make it work
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myClassEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    ... initializations ...
    em.setDataSource(...myDataSource...)
    em.setPackagesToScan("...EntitiesPackagesToScan...")

    em.setPersistenceUnitName(ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME); // Not sure if this is needed, I just added it trying to make it work
  }

  @Bean(name=TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
  @Qualifier(TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) // Not sure if this is needed, I just added it trying to make it work
  public PlatformTransactionManager myClassTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
            myClassEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

And I am trying to reference it from `Services` like this:

**ServiceTemplate**

```
@Service
public class myServiceClass {

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = MyRepoConfigClass.ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) // Thought this might be the solution for JPA PersistenceContext, but did not work anyway
  @Qualifier(MyRepoConfigClasss.ENTITY_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) // Not sure if this is supposed to be done like this. In normal spring boot components it works
  private EntityManager entityManager; // <- This injection fails

}
```

From my point of view, I am specifying exactly what `EntityManger` should use via  either `@PersistenceContext`(**unitName**) or `@Qualifier`

However, as the error says, springboot does not know which one of the 4 Beans use.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Full stack trace:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'changes': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 5: D1EntityManager,D2EntityManager,BaseEntityManager,oldDbEntityManager,deviceApiGwDbConfigurationDbEntityManager
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1383) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.mycompany.device.api.gw.Application.main(Application.java:35) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 5: D1EntityManager,D2EntityManager,BaseEntityManager,oldDbEntityManager,deviceApiGwDbConfigurationDbEntityManager
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1079) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:700) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:673) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:180) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>       ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: Try using `name` of `@PersistenceContext` instead of `unitName`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Did not work. I get exactly the same result :(

Comment: Please add the full stack trace and not a snippet.

Comment: where is a bean called "changes" mentioned in a stacktrace? By the way, it complies on `EntityManagerFactory`, not `EntityManager`.

Comment: Have you tried `@Autowired @Qualifier(...)` instead? Btw you would've made it easier for yourself by simply using method names as qualifiers